# How to extend a class from TADOQuery in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++builder

I'm trying to create extended class from TADOQuery below like.

I've added new unit to project.

Unit2.h

```
#include <ADODB.hpp>

#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
#endif


class TExTADOQuery : public TADOQuery
{
   typedef TADOQuery inherited;
  public:
    __fastcall virtual TExTADOQuery(Classes::TComponent* AOwner);
    __fastcall virtual ~TExTADOQuery(void);
}
```

Unit2.cpp

```
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
```

when I compiling getting that error message.

> [C++ Error] Unit2.cpp(12): E2040 Declaration terminated incorrectly

ADODB.hpp

```
class DELPHICLASS TADOQuery;
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TADOQuery : public TCustomADODataSet 
{
    typedef TCustomADODataSet inherited;

private:
    Classes::TStrings* FSQL;
    int FRowsAffected;
    Classes::TStrings* __fastcall GetSQL(void);
    void __fastcall SetSQL(const Classes::TStrings* Value);

protected:
    void __fastcall QueryChanged(System::TObject* Sender);

public:
    __fastcall virtual TADOQuery(Classes::TComponent* AOwner);
    __fastcall virtual ~TADOQuery(void);
    int __fastcall ExecSQL(void);
    __property int RowsAffected = {read=FRowsAffected, nodefault};

__published:
    __property CommandTimeout  = {default=30};
    __property DataSource ;
    __property EnableBCD  = {default=1};
    __property ParamCheck  = {default=1};
    __property Parameters ;
    __property Prepared  = {default=0};
    __property Classes::TStrings* SQL = {read=GetSQL, write=SetSQL};
};
```

I don't undertand that PASCALIMPLEMENTATION.

How can I declare correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forgot semicolon.

```
class TExTADOQuery : public TADOQuery
{
   typedef TADOQuery inherited;
  public:
    __fastcall virtual TExTADOQuery(Classes::TComponent* AOwner);
    __fastcall virtual ~TExTADOQuery(void);
};
```

Comment: It always happens because of semicolon

Comment: Also, the `#endif` is in the wrong place.  It should be at the end of the file, after the class declaration (otherwise the header guard is meaningless).  Also, the `#include <ADODB.hpp>` should be inside the `#ifndef ... #endif` block as well.  Everything in the header should be inside the guard. The whole point of a header guard is so everything is ignored on subsequent includes after the header has already been included one time, otherwise you end up with "multiple declaration" errors and such.